# Задание аргументов при запуске jar-а

Tags: jar, java

1. Сколько и где задаются аргументы при запуске jar - файла?
2. Как их прочитать в программе?

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае можно сделать так:

```
java -jar myCode.jar param1 param2...
```

В процессе написания вашего когда, вы, по всей видимости воспользуетесь фцнкцией `public static void main(...)`. Данная функция в качестве аргумента принимает массив `String[] args`, который и будет в себе содержать параметры `param1, param2...`

Comment: ... которые в коде достаются так - args[i], номер аргумента(исчисление начинается с нуля)

Пример :

    java -jar myCode.jar param1 param2
    

    public class SupperClass{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        String param1 = args[0];
        String param2 = args[1];
        }
    }

Answer (score 3):

Аргументы задаются после названия jar файла который Вы запускаете. аргументы разделаются пробелом их может быть очень много.
java -jar MyFile.jar par1 par2 par3 par4 ....

Это все передается в main(String[] args) - args и есть массив параметров которые вы передаете

Answer (score 2):

Выполните комадну java без аргументов и получите всю необходимую информацию.