# Запуск EXE при помощи ProcessBuilder с аргументами

Tags: java, exe, exec, процесс

Как запустить тот или иной EXE-файл с входящими аргументами?

```
ProcessBuilder i1 = new ProcessBuilder("file.exe");
//i1.добавитьАргумент("названиеАргумента", "значениеАргумента");
i1.start();
```

То есть, если я буду делать это с помощью BAT-файлов (батч), то выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
start file.exe +set arg1 VALUE +set arg2 VALUE
```

**Примечание:** данный EXE-файл написан не на языке Java, так что подобные варианты ([Задание аргументов при запуске jar-а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/224366/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5-jar-%D0%B0)) не предлагать.

Comment: Возможно, можно обойтись и без ProcessBuilder'а, это ведь не принципиально.

Comment: Начните с чтения официальной документации: new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2"); например

Answer (score 2):

```
new ProcessBuilder("file.exe", "+set", "arg1", "VALUE", "+set", "arg2" "VALUE").start();
```